# Как хранить админ настройки Symfony

Tags: symfony

Создал entity Config, в ней создал нужные поля.
Храню там мелкие настройки: лого, кол-во записей на странице и т.д.
Вывел в админке(easy admin) ссылку на редактирование одной страницы с id=1

```
$configRepo = $entityManager->getRepository(Config::class);
$configRepo->find(1);
```

Возможно, есть какой то другой способ, слишком жирно для 20 полей создавать entity.

Comment: Можете задать параметры через `parameters` в `services.yaml`

Comment: могу, но мне нужно что бы можно было менять значения в админке

Comment: `слишком жирно для 20 полей создавать entity`

Почему ?